How to auto-complete the different command with multiple options from dict?
I am trying to achieve a function that can auto-complete the command with options in dict.
For example: there's two commands
create_clock and set_voltage, two options -wave and -period with create_clock, and one option -value with set_voltage.
create_clock -wave
create_clock -period
set_voltage -value

My goal is that when I type the beginning of a word with c  or cr, it will show me the command create_clock. Then when I type  - it will show me the option  period or wave.
This is my current function; it only can auto-complete the command. When I use - to trigger the option nothing shows. How can I modify the function to achieve the target?
set dictionary=D:\Vim\1.dict
function! Completion(findstart, base)
    if a:findstart
        " Find where to start completion
        let l:line = getline('.')
        let l:pos = col('.') - 1
        let l:start = l:pos - len(matchstr(l:line[0:l:pos], '\S*$'))
        return l:start
    else
        " Path to your dictionary
        let l:dict_file = 'D:/Vim/1.dict'

        " Verify dictionary existence
        if !filereadable(l:dict_file)
            echom "Error: Dictionary file not found: " . l:dict_file
            return []
        endif

        " Parse dictionary into commands and options
        let l:commands = {}
        let l:dict_lines = readfile(l:dict_file)
        for l:line in l:dict_lines
            if l:line =~# '^\(\w\+\)\s\+-\(\w\+\)'
                let l:cmd = matchstr(l:line, '^\w\+')
                let l:opt = matchstr(l:line, '-\w\+')
                if !has_key(l:commands, l:cmd)
                    let l:commands[l:cmd] = []
                endif
                call add(l:commands[l:cmd], l:opt)
            endif
        endfor

        " Get the current line
        let l:line = getline('.')

        " Normalize: Fix spaces around the dash
        let l:normalized_line = substitute(l:line, '\s\+', ' ', 'g')  " Consolidate spaces
        let l:normalized_line = substitute(l:normalized_line, '\s-\+', ' -', 'g') " Ensure space before dash
        echom "Normalized Line: " . l:normalized_line

        " Case 1: Matching commands
        if l:normalized_line !~# '-'
            let l:matches = filter(keys(l:commands), 'v:val =~ "^' . a:base . '"')
            echom "Matching Commands: " . string(l:matches)
            return l:matches
        endif

        " Case 2: Matching options for a specific command
        let l:cmd = matchstr(l:normalized_line, '^\(\w\+\)\s-\+')
        if l:cmd != ''
            if has_key(l:commands, l:cmd)
                let l:matches = filter(l:commands[l:cmd], 'v:val =~ "^' . a:base . '"')
                echom "Matching Options for Command '" . l:cmd . "': " . string(l:matches)
                return l:matches
            endif
        endif

        " Default: No matches
        echom "No matches found."
        return []
    endif
endfunction

" Set omnifunction for all file types
autocmd FileType * setlocal omnifunc=Completion

" Map <Tab> for manual triggering of completion
inoremap <Tab> <C-X><C-O>


I wanted to have this but couldn't figure out. Instead I went the :cabbrev route.

I don't have a fix for you at the moment but it looks like l:normalized_line never actually contains a - so the "Case 2" code path is never taken. If you :echom getline('.') right at the beginning of the function, then you will see that the - is included only on the first invocation but not on the second one, where it matters.

PS you almost certainly don’t want to :set dictionary to this custom file. Using the local variables in the function is the appropriate way to go there.

@D.BenKnoble I have huge amount command and corresponding options, you mean just read the dict in function not outside by set dictionary ?

You, presumably, don't use :help ctrl-x_ctrl-k and &dictionary is not used in your function so it is redundant and irrelevant and can be removed. Or you can keep it and use its value in the function in place of l:dict_file.

@M_Sea see Romain’s comment above. The dictionary option is typically for a specific format

@romainl yeah, worked, using let g:primetime_commands = { \ 'create_clock' : ['-wave', '-period'], \ 'set_voltage'  : ['-value'], \ 'set_frequency' : ['-hz', '-khz'], \ } to define all command and option will make it worked, but i have more than 100 command and every command have 3-8 option, is there any way to easy degfine it instead of manually?

FWIW, if you managed to solve your problem consider writing an answer and accepting it.

Thanks to @romainl’s suggestion, I wrote the below fuction to auto-complete command and options:
let g:commands = { 'create_clock' : ['-wave', '-period'], \
 'set_voltage'  : ['-value'], \ 
'set_frequency' : ['-hz', '-khz'], \
 }

autocmd FileType * setlocal completefunc=Completion

" Define the function for completion
function! Completion(findstart, base)
    if a:findstart
        " Locate where the completion starts (for tab)
        let l:line = getline('.')
        let l:pos = col('.') - 1
        while l:pos > 0 && l:line[l:pos - 1] =~ '\k'
            let l:pos -= 1
        endwhile
        return l:pos
    else
        " Provide options based on what the user has typed
        let l:line = getline('.')
        let l:command = matchstr(l:line, '^\s*\(\w\+\)')  " Extract command from line

        " Debugging output
        echom "Line: " . l:line
        echom "Command: " . l:command
        echom "Base: " . a:base

        " If we detect a command, provide options
        if has_key(g:commands, l:command)
            " If base starts with '-', complete options for the command
            if a:base =~ '^-'
                " Filter and return options for the current command
                let l:options = filter(g:commands[l:command], 'v:val =~ "^' . a:base . '"')
                echom "Options: " . string(l:options)  " Debugging output for options"
                return l:options
            else
                " Return only commands that exactly match the base
                return []
            endif
        else
            " If no valid command is typed yet, match commands based on base
            let l:matches = filter(keys(g:commands), 'v:val =~ "^' . a:base . '"')
            echom "Command Matches: " . string(l:matches)  " Debugging output for commands"
            return l:matches
        endif

        return []
    endif
endfunction


